# Parsing HTML with Jsoup issue in Android Application

Tags: android, html, eclipse, http, jsoup

I am new to android development. I am using Jsoup to parse an URL to get the file location.

Below is the code I have for parsing the URL, It works for most of the URL I inserted.
For example, `www.baidu.com/` or `www.nba.com/`, the title Logged is exactly same as shown in the page source.

However, for `http://music.baidu.com/` the title displayed in the Eclipse Log is different from the page resource.

Eclipse shows: `百度音乐`

Page Resource shows: `<title>百度音乐-中国第一音乐门户</title>`

(This is the most important one I want to solve.)

For `http://music.baidu.com/search?key=%E5%86%8D%E8%A7%81%E7%8E%8B%E5%AD%90+%E6%A3%89%E8%8A%B1%E7%B3%96`

Eclipse again shows `百度音乐`

Page Resource shows `<title>搜索含有"再见王子 棉花糖"的音乐_百度音乐-中国第一音乐门户</title>`

Also, for those 2 webpage, nothing is in Element links, so the `Log.d("text", link.text());` never returns anything.

I notice that the 2 webpages source does not have `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">` in HTML like other HTML has.

```
package com.example.htmlparser;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //set layout view
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {                     
            public void run() {            
                Document doc;                                      
                try {                                                        
                    String url = "";
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    //doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", url);
                    String title = doc.title();
                    Log.d("title", title);

                    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                    for (Element link : links) {
                        //Log.d("link", link.attr("href").toString());
                        Log.d("text", link.text());
                    }                
                } catch (IOException e) {                          
                    Log.d("exception", e.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        downloadThread.start();    
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse showed the correct Title for me once i ran your code. But to make sure is getting ur title you can try this:

```
 String title = doc.select("head title").text();
         System.out.println("title: "+ title);
```

i hope it helps